How can I edit files in `/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/` to survive reboots?
I am setting up Netdata on a Debian 12 VPS at Hetzner Cloud. Part of the preflight is to ensure two files in /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/ are set to the required values:

/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run should be 1; it's currently 0.
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs should be 1000; it's currently 20.

My route of rm -> echo + tee -> chown -> chmod is failing at the first step as I am not permitted to rm -f either file:
$ sudo rm -f /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
rm: cannot remove '/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run': Operation not permitted

Using sed in-place also fails with Permission denied.
What's the safest / sanest way to make persistent changes to /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/, please?

One last quick check: what is the output of echo 1 |sudo sh -c 'cat > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run'?

@Joshua - running echo 1 |sudo sh -c 'cat > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run' completes without error, and cat-ing the file does indeed confirm 1. This does appear to a survive a reboot command.

@PeteCooper those files are initialized by the kernel’s source code. If you edit the source code, you can change the default values.

/sys is a synthetic filesystem that is not associated with any persistent storage on the system. In essence, it’s just faked file-like access to a bunch of internals of the kernel. This means nothing written there will ever survive a reboot, and you need to ensure that any changes you want to make get applied on every reboot. Userspace intentionally cannot (directly) create or remove files there either; if you want a new value in a file, just echo the new value to that file. You also should not be modifying permissions on things there arbitrarily (this is very likely to break things in unexpected ways).
Sometimes, it’s possible to change default values for some parameters in /sys from the kernel command line. For example, transparent_hugepage can be used to set the initial value for /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled. KSM, however, does not have any associated kernel command line options as far as I know.
In an ideal world, you would write up a service file for your system’s service manager that sets the required parameters when started (and, in an even more ideal world, resets them to their defaults when stopped, because that makes it easier to test things).
However, there’s an easier approach on most Linux distributions if you don’t want to go for the proper service-based approach. All systemd-based systems, and a handful of non-systemd-based systems, use systemd-tmpfiles to manage things like creation of required temporary directories. And, rather usefully, one of the things it can do is write out arbitrary data to arbitrary files. You can create a file called something like ksm.conf in /etc/tmpfiles.d with the following contents to have the specific values you are asking for in the original question written out every time the system boots up (and in theory, also every time systemd-tmpfiles gets run with the --create option):
f /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_milisecs 644 root root 1000
f /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run 644 root root 1

The first character indicates what to do (f means to create or update a file), the second field is the specific path to create/modify, and the remaining fields are specific to the operation. For f, the third, fourth, and fifth fields indicate the mode, owner, and group, and the rest of the line is the value to write out to the file.
Full details on the format can be found in man tmpfiles.d.

You cannot do it that way. The entire /sys filesystem is recreated at boot, and isn't used for controlling the system. Use /proc instead, see https://www.tecmint.com/change-modify-linux-kernel-runtime-parameters/ and read man proc. You'll have to add the appropriate sysctl commands to your system startup. See the systemd section of https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup

There are no equivalents to these settings in /proc. BTW if you want to set /proc/sys settings at boot, see man sysctl.d — there’s no need for a startup script. But a startup script would allow you to set /sys parameters!

"The entire /sys filesystem [...] isn't used for controlling the system." - It absolutely is.
